# when i submit at then time give an error 'Cannot POST /signin' but when i press 'ctrl+l' at that time data will get in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var db = mongoose.connection;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.use(bodyparser.json());
router.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.post('/singin/data',function(req,res){
    console.log('post inside');
    var fname = req.body.fname;
    var lname = req.body.lname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var data = {
    'fname':fname,
    'lname':lname,
    'email':email,
    'password':password
    }
    db.collection('signup').insertOne(data,function(err,info){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Inserted",info);
    });
    console.log(email);
    res.redirect('signin');
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

> **in get method i get data properly but in post method i can't post
> data into database..
>
> i create mongoose schema also in another models folder and also install mongoose also but major problem is on submit form button i get error can't post /signin**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use your model from mongoose (import) and depends on the version of DB you can try with de deprecate method save()

```
router.post('/singin/data',function(req,res){
    console.log('post inside');
    var fname = req.body.fname;
    var lname = req.body.lname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var data = new USERMODEL({
    'fname':fname,
    'lname':lname,
    'email':email,
    'password':password
    })
    db.collection('signup').save(data, (err, result) => {
  if (err){
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'something is wrong' })
    //return next(err);
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' })
    //return next();
  }
})
```